# HTML Scraping AJAX Paging Table in PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to scrape a webpage that has an AJAX paging html table. I can get the first page of the table fine but I want to be able to get every single page in the table. Here is an [example](https://rn21.ultipro.com/SQU1001/jobboard/listjobs.aspx?Page=Browse) of an ajax paging table.

This how I am currently scraping the first page:

```
   <?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    class JobPosting {
        var $Id;
        var $RequistionNumber;
        var $Title;
        var $JobCategory;
        var $EmployeeClassification;
        var $PartTime; 
        var $City;
        var $Location;     
    }

    function GetJobPostings($filter)
    {
        $html = file_get_html('https://rn21.ultipro.com/SQU1001/jobboard/listjobs.aspx');

        $JobPostings = array();
        $headerFlag = true;

        foreach($html->find('table.GridTable > tbody > tr') as $job) 
        {
            if($headerFlag == true)
            {
               $headerFlag = false; 
            }
            else
            {
                $count = 0;
                $jobposting = new JobPosting;

                foreach($job->find('td') as $property)
                {
                    switch ($count) {
                        case 0:
                            $jobposting->Id = $property->find('a')[0]->href;
                            $jobposting->RequistionNumber = $property->plaintext;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            $jobposting->Title = $property->plaintext;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $jobposting->JobCategory = $property->plaintext;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $jobposting->EmployeeClassification = $property->plaintext;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            $jobposting->PartTime = $property->plaintext;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            $jobposting->City = $property->plaintext;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            $jobposting->Location = $property->plaintext;
                            break;
                    }       
                    $count++;
                }

                if($jobposting->Company == $filter )
                {
                    array_push($JobPostings, $jobposting);
                }      
            }

        }

        return $JobPostings;
    }
    ?>
```

How can I get all the job postings from this website?

Here is the request from fiddler for the example:

[image]

Comment: I can only see 1 page with 17 records.

Comment: Figure out what request the ajax is making and make the same request (using the appropriate page number) for each page. There is most likely some element on the page that contains the highest page number.

Comment: @PedroLobito I just noticed that too. The second example has several pages. I believe that they make the same calls so it should be very similar.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have used fiddler to view the the calls being made but it appears that they have a viewstate id or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the `POST` content, search for `__PreparedPXDO` and change the value of `__PageNumber`:

```
__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUENTM4MWRk8%2BV34Sl40tIYo214geiPudK8q8E%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=0906FCBB&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWDQLRjdiVBQLZmLPIBwLRmtKmBwLJvYapAwKduOGWBgKC9qGSBQL99cOUCAK2xqmfDQKj96rgDQLLvLGTDwLArLTaDQKD%2BaqJAQLUpr%2FLD8lqfch4SOH0EsNlMYgxMFw%2FPlV6&__PXPOSTBACK=1&__PXLBN=&__PXLBV=&__PXDO=&__Keywords=&__RecordsPerPage=&__PreparedPXDO=*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&__PageNumber=  ->HERE<-  &__Next=+%3E+
```

---

You can easily create a loop to scrap all available pages, i.e.:

```
<?php
$num = 1;
while($num < 5){
$postFields = "__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUENTM4MWRk8%2BV34Sl40tIYo214geiPudK8q8E%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=0906FCBB&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWDQLRjdiVBQLZmLPIBwLRmtKmBwLJvYapAwKduOGWBgKC9qGSBQL99cOUCAK2xqmfDQKj96rgDQLLvLGTDwLArLTaDQKD%2BaqJAQLUpr%2FLD8lqfch4SOH0EsNlMYgxMFw%2FPlV6&__PXPOSTBACK=1&__PXLBN=&__PXLBV=&__PXDO=&__Keywords=&__RecordsPerPage=&__PreparedPXDO=*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&__PageNumber=$num&__Next=+%3E+";

$curlHeaders = array(
"Host: rn21.ultipro.com",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0",
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
"Referer: https://rn21.ultipro.com/SQU1001/jobboard/listjobs.aspx?Page=Browse",
"Cookie: __jbsrcid=*86EE06D72F666815; ASP.NET_SessionId=3vvj3v55gadspcyklbfg2gip; BIGipServerrn21.ultipro.com_http_pool=366258698.20480.0000",
"Connection: keep-alive",
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Content-Length: " . strlen($postFields)
);

$url = "https://rn21.ultipro.com/SQU1001/jobboard/listjobs.aspx?Page=Browse";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

$num++;
}
?>
```

---

The *trick* is to make a first post (next page button) using a normal browser and **sniff** the post content using [live http headers for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers-fixed-by-dan/), or similar, and emulate it after using curl.
I've tested the code above and I was able to retrieve all job posts on the website.

Comment: So shouldn't I be able to use this url: https://rn21.ultipro.com/SQU1001/jobboard/listjobs.aspx? and append ur answer and it should bring back a specified page?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. If my answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer, thank you !

Comment: Thanks Pedro, is your echo statement printing out the result? Mine is empty.

Comment: I am getting this curl error:Curl error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: I added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); it works now. Thank you!